# mathematical induction methods

Tags: induction

Mathematical induction I know there is one specific way of proving it which is say for instance the example:

**Method 1**

Prove using mathematical induction that:
$$2^n>n+4, n\ge 3$$

I will skip straight to the induction step:
We assume $P(k)$ is true and hence we have:
$$2^k>k+4, k\ge 3$$
Now $P(k+1)$ states that:
$$2^{k+1}=2\times2^{k}, k\ge 3$$
$$2^{k+1}=2\times2^{k}> 2(k+4)=2k+8>k+8>k+5=(k+1)+4 , k\ge 3$$
$$2^{k+1}>(k+1)+4$$

**Alternative Method:**

Going straight to the induction step:

$$2^k>k+4, k\ge 3$$
$$2^{k+1}>(k+1)+4$$
$$2\times 2^k-k-5>0$$
$$2\times 2^k-k-5>2(k+4)-k-5>0$$
$$2\times 2^k-k-5>k+3>0$$

But this is true as $k\ge 3$.

My question is, are both methods valid and is this valid for any mathematical induction inequality problems?

Comment: Your alternative method breaks down when you go from $2\times 2^k-k-5\gt 0$ to $2\times 2^k-k-5\gt 2(k+4)-k-5\gt 0$. Note that $x\gt 0$ and $x\gt y$ doesn't imply $x\gt y\gt 0$

Comment: Why on earth would the alternative method be valid?  Why would you assume $2^{k+1} > 2^k + 1$... if that is what you were assuming.  Also it is very unclear what your "Methods" are.  These are specific to this question about an exponential value's inequality to a linear value.  How what you apply this to any other question, say a question about the number of divisors, or number of combinations, or paths?

Comment: Learner But we are saying $y>0$ and therefore $x>y $ implies $x>y>0.$

Answer (score 1):

Basically you did the same thing twice with a different form. Anyway I don't like that you write $$2^{k+1}>(k+1)+4$$ since this is to be proved. It is better to write $$2^{k+1}-(k+1)-4=...$$

and estimate that expression. And after all, if you write first one it is better to write it like this:

$$2^{k+1}\stackrel{?}{>}(k+1)+4$$

Comment: Could you elaborate further on this? What do you mean it is better to write it in that form? i have already did and made approximations  acoordignly from there?